# Reusing JSP custom tags inside html

Tags: jsp-tags

Is there any way to  reuse jsp -custom tags inside a html file?

My custom tag is already defined in a tld file and I am using that custom tag in a jsp file.

I want to reuse that custom tag in a html file.

How do I do this?

Below is the sample example of using my custom tag(btc:content) in a jsp file.

```
<div class="sfl-section-body">
<btc:content name="HOL-CF-307" />
```

I want to use (my custom tag) in an html file.

Comment: Can you show your code and what you've tried? Good question it just needs some context.

Comment: If I am using below content in a jsp file ,its fine.(btc:content is my custom tag)

<div class="sfl-section-body">
 <btc:content name="HOL-CF-021" />
</div>

Now how can I use the same line:
<btc:content name="HOL-CF-021" />
in an html file???

Comment: Edit your question with more of the code, not just a few lines.